# Getting data from multiple tables to update a column

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta
set meta_value = 'a:1:{i:0;s:6:"Subbed";}' 
WHERE meta_key = 'episode_sdversion'
```

This is basically how far I am able to get. This just simply means I want to update the `wp_postmeta` table and set the column `meta_value` to `a:1:{i:0;s:6:"Subbed";}` when `meta_key` is `episode_sdversion` this is fine.

Here is the problem, I want to retrieve another WHERE clause. But to get that "WHERE" I need to retrieve the information from multiple tables.

From table wp_terms column `name` that has the first word "Subbed" I grab the ID from term_id column. So I guess that would work like this

```
SELECT term_id
FROM  `wp_terms` 
WHERE  `name` LIKE  '%Subbed %'
```

Then use that term_id value that you just retrieved in table `wp_term_relationships`
and check if it's equal to the value in column `term_taxonomy_id` and then in the `object_id` column WHERE `term_taxonomy_id = whatever you just got from before`. And that `object_id` would be equal to the `post_id` column in the `wp_postmeta` which is going to be my second WHERE clause...

so my final code will look something similar to this

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta
set meta_value = 'a:1:{i:0;s:6:"Subbed";}' 
WHERE meta_key = 'episode_sdversion'
AND WHERE post_id = the ID that I am trying to get from going through different tables
```

Also can I use a `WHERE meta_value = ''` ... so only set the meta_value to `a:1:{i:0;s:6:"Subbed";}` when `meta_value = ''` blank...

So if you guys have any idea on how to get information from other tables and keep it in some sort of variable and then refer to it in your final query, that would be great, or combining multiple queries?

Answer (score 0):

This is a crappy way to do it. If someone comes along and posts a pure joined solution, use that. Also, I can barely decipher all of the tables your using, and what exactly you're trying to do so this is my best effort at reading your mind.

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta
set meta_value = 'a:1:blahblbah'
WHERE meta_key='episode_sdversion'
  AND post_id in(SELECT post_id FROM wp_terms WHERE name like '%Subbed%');
```

You have a join that it looks like you need to accomplish in your subquery, but from your post I cannot tell what that is. If you cannot figure it out from here, post more info about the other table but it'll be like:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta
set meta_value = 'a:1:blahblbah'
WHERE meta_key='episode_sdversion'
  AND post_id in(SELECT post_id
    FROM wp_terms 
    JOIN OTHERTABLE on OTHERTABLE.PK=wp_terms.PK
    WHERE name like '%Subbed%' and OTHERTABLE.WhateverColumn='whatevervalue');
```

That's the best I can do given the info. Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

I agree -- your question is very difficult to understand.  If you could post your table structure, sample data, and desired output, this would make it a lot easier.

However, if I'm understanding your requirements correctly, then this should be close:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta
SET meta_value = 'a:1:{i:0;s:6:"Subbed";}' 
WHERE meta_key = 'episode_sdversion' AND
    post_id IN (
       SELECT tr.object_id 
       FROM  wp_terms t
          JOIN wp_term_relationships tr ON t.term_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id 
       WHERE  t.name LIKE '%Subbed %'   
   ) AND meta_value = ''
```

This also might work if my understandings are correct:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta pm
    JOIN wp_term_relationships tr ON pm.post_id = tr.object_id
    JOIN wp_terms t ON t.term_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id 
SET pm.meta_value = 'a:1:{i:0;s:6:"Subbed";}' 
WHERE pm.meta_key = 'episode_sdversion'
    AND t.name LIKE '%Subbed %' 
    AND meta_value = ''
```